# Let $X$ be a metric space and $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \ldots$ subsets of $X$. Show that the intersection of each $A_n$ is non-empty and compact.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \ldots$ decreasing sequence of non-empty compact subsets of $X$. Show that the intersection of each $A_n$ is non-empty and compact.

I'm having trouble showing this. If $X$ is not compact then wouldn't $A_n = [n, \infty)$ be an immediate counterexample? I assume that they missed to state that $X$ is compact? I saw this question here previously where $X$ was stated to be complete, but found this on a topology book, but they didn't state anything else than $X$ being a metric space.

Comment: $A_2^{c},A_3^{c},...$  is an open cover of $A_1$.

Comment: This sort of fact is true for a nested sequence of closed sets, if it least one $A_n$ is compact or (metric version) if $X$ is complete metric and moreover the diameters of the $A_n$ tend to $0$. In the latter case the intersection is exactly a singleton. In the former compact and non-empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All $A_n$ must be compact and $[n, \infty)$ is not compact. "The intersection of each $A_n$" is ungrammatical in English, you mean $A:=\bigcap_n A_n$, the intersection of *all* $A_n$ (which is different).

Answer (score 0):

The key detail here is that the $A_n$ are all compact subsets of $X$. That would preclude the obvious counterexample you raised.

Answer (score 0):

Kavi Rama Murthy answered it. Supposing the intersection is empty, we have that $A_k^c, k=2,3,...$ is an open cover of the compact $A_1$. This open cover though has no finite sub cover since all $A_k$’s are nonempty. This contradicts the compactness of $A_1$.